# Inconsistent representation of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume we've made the following assignment:

```
x = (1, 2, (3, 'John', 4), 'Hi')
```

Why does `x[0:1]` gives me `(1,)` but `x[0:-1]` gives `(1, 2, (3, 'John', 4))`? Why is there no comma after `(3, 'John', 4)`?

Comment: `(1)` is not a tuple, it's an int object wrapped with parens. Python does without the comma when it can; minimal.

Comment: Its just syntactic sugar to distinguish brackets around something from a tuple containing a single item. Once you can tell its a tuple, then you don't need the trailing comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever you are working on a tuple and there is a single element it ends with a comma like in your first case (1,). As in the second case (1, 2, (3, 'John', 4)) there is more than one element, it does not end with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses don't define a tuple; commas do. Normally, the commas occur *between* elements, but a 1-tuple needs to be special-cased somewhat because there is no second element to provide a medial position for the comma.

Parentheses are only needed when working with tuples where necessary to distinguish different uses of commas, and in the special case of the empty tuple.

```
# empty tuple
# There's no such thing syntactically as an empty expression, so
# parentheses can be used.
x = ()

# 1-tuple - the comma signals a tuple is being created; no need for parentheses here, but they can be optionally used.
x = 1,
y = (1,)  # x == y

# n-tuples. A trailing comma is allowed but has no affect.
x = 1,2
y = 1,2,  # x == y
```